# How to SELECT from table, when the condition is depending on rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

Help needed please.
I have a trouble with a select.
I have a table containing probation periods with following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE probation (
  pk_person int,
  p_startdate datetime,
  p_enddate datetime,
  PRIMARY KEY (pk_person )
)
```

and a table containing persons absences with following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE absences (
  pk_person int,
  a_startdate datetime,
  a_enddate datetime,
)
```

Now, i need to calculate the end of the probation period for person. The problem is that the absences effectively prolongs the probation period.
For example:

```
insert into probation (pk_person, p_startdate, p_enddate) values (1, 01-01-2001, 31-03-2001)
insert into absences (pk_person, a_startdate, a_enddate) values (1, 01-02-2001, 28-02-2001)
insert into absences (pk_person, a_startdate, a_enddate) values (1, 01-04-2001, 10-04-2001)
```

Now i need to select the complete probation period for person with the following result:

```
pk_person, startdate, enddate
1          01-01-2001 08-05-2001
```

I could use a stored procedure, but can't do it for reasons.
I'm using MSSQL 2008.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Select

Int

Big list.Start date

Big list. End date

Datediff(day, big list.start date, big list.end date) as original duration

Sum(datediff(day, small list.start date, small list.end date) as total extra time

DateAdd(day, big list.start date,
Sum(datediff(day, small list.start date, small list.end date))        as new end date

From

Big list

Left outer join small list on big list.int = small list.int

Group by

Big list.everything

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what i meant. Will try to explain. There also can be absences that we have to discard, if the absentee continues working and there are registered absences long after.